# Contenteditable table

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue3

У меня есть таблица которую можно редактировать.
Но при редактировании когда ставишь пробел появляется такое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно ответ в коде, который Вы от нас утаили?

Comment: С проблемой копипаста ещё не столкнулся?)